# Взаимодействие AJAX и Perl.

Tags: ajax, perl

Здравствуйте!

Возникла необходимость проверять совпадение данных из БД с данными, которые ввел пользователь.(Нечто вроде обычной проверки на занятость логина).

Нужно чтобы проверка происходила без перезагрузки страницы, поэтому решил использовать **ajax**, но нигде не смог найти взаимодействие с perl.

Cобственно саму проверку на jQuery я разобрался как написать, но везде приводится в пример PHP код на подобие этого:

```
if(isset($_GET['login'])){
 $login = $_GET['login'];
 if($login == 'user'){
     echo "no";
 }else{
      echo "yes";
 }
}
```

Подскажите как реализовать подобное в perl-скрипте?

Comment: так-же как и с неajax - [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.43/CGI.pm)

Comment: почитайте про [OpenAPI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::OpenAPI) и [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAPI_(%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Ajax отправляете, например, GET http://yourdomain.com/check_login?login=user123.

На сервере вам нужно проверить, что пользователя user123 ещё нет в базе. Для этого вам нужно получить значение параметра 'login' из URL. Как именно вы будете получать его с помощью Perl, зависит от используемого фреймворка / технологии. CGI, про который уже говорили, сейчас редко кем используется - есть множество более удобных фреймворков для написания серверной части веб-приложений на Perl - например, [Dancer](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer).

При использовании Dancer для получения значения параметра login можно использовать, например, следующий код:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Dancer;

# Возвращать ответ будем в формате JSON
setting serializer => 'JSON';

get '/check_login' => sub {
    my $login = param('login');

    if (login_exists($login)) {
        return { login => { exists => $login } };
    }
    # Если такого пользователя ещё нет, говорим, что логин не занят
    return { login => { available => $login } };
};
dance;

sub login_exists {
    my $login = shift;

    # Здесь проверяете, существует ли такой логин в вашей базе.
    # Для взаимодействия с БД можно использовать, например, Dancer::Plugin::Database
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно как-то так:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(param);

if (param('login')) {
    if (param('login') eq 'user') {
        print 'no';
    }
    else {
        print 'yes';
    }
}
```